# SegNetプログラムが実行できない問題

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/uni-3/items/a62daa5a03a02f5fa46d)に掲載されているSegNetのプログラムを拝借して実行したところ、datasetプログラムで下記のようなエラーが発生するようになってしまいました。

これはTensorFlowがインポートできていないということなのでしょうか？一応、KerasやTensorFlow関係のパッケージはインストールしてあるのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。
（パッケージのインストールは、Anaconda Navigator 上で行いました。）

> runfile('C:/Users/ユーザ名/.spyder-py3/dataset.py', wdir='C:/Users/t.k/.spyder-py3')
>   Using TensorFlow backend.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "＜ipython-input-6-ef8e060fac88＞", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/ユーザ名/.spyder-py3/dataset.py', wdir='C:/Users/t.k/.spyder-py3')
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/ユーザ名/.spyder-py3/dataset.py", line 11, in 
>       from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py", line 3, in 
>       from . import utils
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py", line 6, in 
>       from . import conv_utils
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
>       from .. import backend as K
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py", line 89, in 
>       from .tensorflow_backend import *
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>
> File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>
> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
>     File "C:\Users\ユーザ名\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

原因がわからないので、解決策を教えていただきたいです。

開発環境
 - Windows7 (64bit)
 - Spyder (Python3.6)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/162216

Comment: 過去の質問についてマルチポスト先で解決したなら、SOにも自己回答をお願いします。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

マルチポスト先で、自己解決いたしました。

Comment: 回答の内容を記載するようにしてください。

Comment: PCを別のもの（メモリやGPUの性能が高い方）に換えて実行したところ、エラーがでなくなりました。